# Jsp request is not going to java servlet class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a table which contains records with view, update , delete icons.
on click view & update i am passing my request to some other jsp. on click delete icon the request needs to go my servlet class. There it should execute delete query.

This is my table

[image]

on click delete icon i am getting the id & delete values in the url. see the image. But the request is not going to java servlet.

[image]

Here is my code

Jsp Code:

```
<%
    FormRegistration fr = new FormRegistration();
    List<UserDetailsBean> list = fr.getUserDetails();
   %>
<form method="post" action="./BrightSymphonyController" >
 <%
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
  %>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th style="display: none;">ID</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <td>
          <a href="./BrightSymphonyController?id=<%=list.get(i).getId()%>&delete=Delete" class="urlImgDelete" title="Delete"><!--here i have delete icon -->
          </a>
        </td>
    <%}%>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Servlet class:

```
@WebServlet("/BrightSymphonyController")
public class BrightSymphonyController extends HttpServlet {
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public BrightSymphonyController() {
    //super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse       response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String deleteuser = request.getParameter("delete");
        System.out.println("deleteuser============"+deleteuser);
        String id=request.getParameter("id");
        System.out.println("id============"+id);
        }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <display-name>brightsymphony</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>BrightSymphony</servlet-name>
<servle-class>com.s2s.brightsymphony.controller.BrightSymphonyController
</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>BrightSymphony</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/BrightSymphony</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the get parameters , move your code from doPost() to doGet() method as follows

```
@WebServlet("/BrightSymphonyController")
public class BrightSymphonyController extends HttpServlet {
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public BrightSymphonyController() {
    //super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse       response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String deleteuser = request.getParameter("delete");
        System.out.println("deleteuser============"+deleteuser);
        String id=request.getParameter("id");
        System.out.println("id============"+id);
}
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        }
}
```

Comment: Yes @Zaheer Khorajiya its working. Can you please explain how the process is going in servlet & jsp. To another jsp also i am sending get parameters only na.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code from `doPost()` to `doGet()`

`href` sends the request as `get` not `post` , your aren't using the `form` to send the request `post` your request is send from `href`

If you want the request to be sent as `post`

```jsp
<form method="post" action="./BrightSymphonyController" >
 <%
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
  %>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th style="display: none;">ID</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <td>
          <input type="submit" class="urlImgDelete" value="Delete" /> 
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=list.get(i).getId()%>"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="Delete" />
        </td>
    <%}%>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this

```
<a href="<%=request.ContextPath()%>/BrightSymphonyController?id=<%=list.get(i).getId()%>&delete=Delete" class="urlImgDelete" title="Delete">
```

insted of

```
  <a href="./BrightSymphonyController?id=<%=list.get(i).getId()%>&delete=Delete" class="urlImgDelete" title="Delete">
```

I hope this will help!!!!

Comment: It is showing this error --"The method ContextPath() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest".

Comment: sorry my mistake it's getContextPath()